# Ruby on Rails 4 with SendGrid - authentication fails , but only on production server on Linode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, sendgrid

In my application I have set up sendgrid SMTP service. I am using Figaro gem for setting ENV variables for SMTP configuration.

Everything is fine on development mode - I can send e-mails. But when I deploy to my VPS on Linode, every time when I try to send mail I get:

`Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password`

On the Rails console of the production server I can verify that `ENV["GRID_USER']` and `ENV["GRID_PASS"]` are correct. The same result I get when I'm checking for `Figaro.env.grid_user` and `Figaro.env.grid_pass` (in production mode). 
The credentials are correct.

What could be the reason for failing authentication, surprisingly only in production mode?

Here you can see my smtp config in `production.rb` :

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    user_name: ENV['GRID_USER'],
    password: ['GRID_PASS'],
    domain: "why.bio",
    port: 587,
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
    }
```

Here is the way I declare my credentials in `application.yml` :

```
GRID_USER: "MySendGridUserName"
GRID_PASS: "very_wierd_password"
```

I have checked a hundreds of questions in StackOverflow and a number of blogs, but could not find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ENV['GRID_PASS']` and not just `['GRID_PASS']` in your configuration.

Comment: Thank you, Bryce. It took me a whole weekend. I wish I had your accurate eyes.

Comment: Haha, no worries!  I've wasted longer amounts of time on syntax errors before as well! Best of luck with the rest of your coding!

Comment: You saved my day, indeed. Be happy, Bryce.